# How to access variable declared inside a functional component in other functions

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Stuffing the functions inside `FoodSearch()` isn't good practice since the other functions would be defined every time the component is rendered. However, when I put the functions outside of `FoodSearch()`, the variables become undefined.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function handleChange(e) {
  setQuery(e.target.value);
}

function handleClick(e) {
  // e.preventDefault();
  history(`/food/${query}`);
}

function FoodSearch() {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const history = useNavigate()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Search For A Food!</h1>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder='search for a food'
        value={query}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Link to={`/food/${query}`}>Go!</Link>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Save New Food!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default FoodSearch;
```

I'm a beginner in react and trying to learn

Comment: "Stuffing the functions inside `FoodSearch()` isn't good practice since the other functions would be defined every time the component is rendered." - Says who? Defining the callback handlers in the component is necessary, and completely normal. This code doesn't appear to be complex enough to warrant any optimization. Don't prematurely optimize. Are you facing any actual issue with the functions defined in the component?

Comment: There are no issues when I include them inside the component. I just wanted to know if there is a better way so that in bigger & more complex projects in the future the proper optimization will be made. Nonetheless, I will be defining the callbacks in the component from now on

Comment: Define them in the component using them. If they are referenced in other React hooks' dependencies or passed down as props to children, ***and*** are triggering excessive rerenders, *that* is when you should look to memoize them and provide stable references.

Answer (score -1):

You should define them inside `FoodSearch` but wrap in a [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to memoize the returned function. That way they won't change unless a dependency (e.g. `query`) changes.